How to input decimal numbers for a PHP cALCULATOR
I'm trying to learn PHP and I'm watching Dani Krossing's tutorial. I was able to follow his tutorial and was able to build a calculator using HTML and PHP. But I ran into a problem, whenever I'm trying to input a decimal number, it removes the '.' sign and is making it whole number. So if I add 12.3 and 3 the result is 126 instead of 15.3. I tried to check any options online but nothing seems to work. Below is the code I used
HTML FORM:
<h2>Calculator Activity</h2>
    
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="num01" placeholder="Number one">
        <select name="operator">
            <option value="add">+</option>
            <option value="subtract">-</option>
            <option value="multiply">*</option>
            <option value="divide">/</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="num02" placeholder="Number two">
        <button>Calculate</button>
    </form>

PHP CODE:
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            //Grab data from the form and sanitize

            $num01 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "num01", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
            $num02 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "num02", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
            $operator = htmlspecialchars($_POST["operator"]);

            // Error Handlers
            $errors = false;

            if(empty($num01) || empty($num02) || empty($operator)) {
                echo "Fill in all fields!";
                $errors = true;
            }
            
            if (!is_numeric($num01) || !is_numeric($num02)) {
                echo "Only numeric characters are allowed!";
                $errors = true;
            }

            // Calculate numbers if no erros
            if (!$errors) {
                $value = 0;
                switch ($operator) {
                    case "add":
                        $value = $num01 + $num02;
                        break;
                    case "subtract":
                        $value = $num01 - $num02;
                        break;
                    case "multiply":
                        $value = $num01 * $num02;
                        break;
                    case "divide":
                        $value = $num01 / $num02;
                        break;
                    default:
                        echo "Something went wrong!";
                }
                echo "Result = ".$value;
            }

        }
    ?>

Thank you in advance!
Any possible option to make this work for decimal inputs?

empty($num01) would give a false positive if $num01 equals zero. Avoid empty() in all php code.

For your case, the lines filter_input(INPUT_POST, xxxx, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT); are causing problem.
It is because the FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT filter removes all "illegal characters" (it considers) from a float number.
For your case, which you want to process numbers with decimal places, one of the ways will be to replace
$num01 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "num01", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$num02 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "num02", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT); 

with
$num01=$_POST["num01"];
$num02=$_POST["num02"];

So the resulting code will be
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            //Grab data from the form and sanitize

//            $num01 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "num01", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
//            $num02 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "num02", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);

$num01=$_POST["num01"];
$num02=$_POST["num02"];


            $operator = htmlspecialchars($_POST["operator"]);

            // Error Handlers
            $errors = false;

            if(empty($num01) || empty($num02) || empty($operator)) {
                echo "Fill in all fields!";
                $errors = true;
            }
            
            if (!is_numeric($num01) || !is_numeric($num02)) {
                echo "Only numeric characters are allowed!";
                $errors = true;
            }

            // Calculate numbers if no erros
            if (!$errors) {
                $value = 0;
                switch ($operator) {
                    case "add":
                        $value = $num01 + $num02;
                        break;
                    case "subtract":
                        $value = $num01 - $num02;
                        break;
                    case "multiply":
                        $value = $num01 * $num02;
                        break;
                    case "divide":
                        $value = $num01 / $num02;
                        break;
                    default:
                        echo "Something went wrong!";
                }
                echo "Result = ".$value;
            }

        }
    ?>

<h2>Calculator Activity</h2>
    
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="num01" placeholder="Number one">
        <select name="operator">
            <option value="add">+</option>
            <option value="subtract">-</option>
            <option value="multiply">*</option>
            <option value="divide">/</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="num02" placeholder="Number two">
        <button>Calculate</button>
    </form>


Thank you so much for checking it. I just want to know if I were to protect my form from malicious codes, given that we've removed the FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, what are my other options if there is?

Since your calculator has no access to personal data (I do not find any code relating to database table data access in your code), there is acutally no need to "protect" your form from malicious codes right now . By the way, if later you amend your calculator to have database access, then please use parameterized prepared statements in all SQL queries instead of the filter_sanitize_* function for data protection.

I see. I will take note of that and will check on it once I get there. I appreciate your time answering my question. Have a great day!
